# Grant execute privilege on specific database

Tags: mysql, sql-grant

I tried granting the execute privilege for a specific user on a specific database using the following:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON `databasename`.* TO 'user'@'12.345.67.89';
```

It appears to complete successfully but doesn't add the permission. However if the execute permission is granted globally for the same user - it works! Am I missing something?

Using mysql version 5.0.51a

Comment: What does SHOW GRANTS FOR 'user'@'12.345.67.89' return?

Comment: @Devart it says `GRANT EXECUTE ON *.* TO 'user'@'12.345.67.89' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'xyz'` and `GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, INDEX, ALTER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES ON databasename.* TO 'user'@'12.345.67.89'`

Comment: It's very strange. I cannot reproduce it (tried on MySQL 5.0.87, 5.5.12).